# Angular 4 add checkboxes to select list

Tags: angular, checkbox

I need to add checkboxes to existing select list in Angular 4

Here is my code for select list and it works fine:

```
<select formControlName=selectItems" name="selectItems" class="form-control" 
 id="selectItems" (change)="selectItem($event)" required>
 <option value="">- Select -</option>
 <option *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"> {{item}}</option>
</select>
```

I need to add a checkbox in front of every item in select list so user could do multiple selections.
Tried few options but nothing worked so far.

What would be a good approach to resolve this task?

Comment: if this is a checkbox, it is not a select box anymore... you must not use options but inputs...

Comment: As far as I'm aware, using a checkbox as a child of either `select` or `option` is invalid HTML-- would need to create a custom component using divs

Comment: An alternative is to set the `multiple` attribute on the `select` element. It displays the element as a list (not a dropdown) and allows multiple selection.

Answer (score 0):

yo have to create custom component to do that.

or just use angular material like this:

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Toppings" [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**TS**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

/** @title Select with multiple selection */
@Component({
  selector: 'select-multiple-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-multiple-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-multiple-example.css'],
})
export class SelectMultipleExample {
  toppings = new FormControl();
  toppingList: string[] = ['Extra cheese', 'Mushroom', 'Onion', 'Pepperoni', 'Sausage', 'Tomato'];
}
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/angular/egkdgobgevx?file=app%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts